# RealmSwift.List reversed

Tags: swift, realm-list

Please validate the following: I need to make out of a RealmSwift.List a reversed RealmSwift.List

Tried to use swift arrays of objects in view model in the legacy code,
but the teamlead and teammates insist on dragging RealmSwift.List everywhere

So in case this makes sense is there a native conversion bypassing array as an intermediary?

This is as open ended question as it could be at this point. Sorry about that.

Comment: `RealmSwift.List` has `swap(At)`, `insert()`, `append()`, `subscript()`... (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Classes/List.html), I guess you can iteratee it and change the order as needed. But for your issue it's opinion based...

Comment: I guess my question was about the utility of dragging transformed lists as ... Lists vs swift arrays